# How to return body from a Angular promise?

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

How to return the body from the response received from an angular promise. Below is the output. I want the data from the third body which i am not sure how can i retreive. Again i am not sure why i am getting nested body for a promise. Please advise.

[image]

Below code :

```
  fetch = () => {   
    debugger;   
    let url  = `${environment.api}${Paths.FetchData}`+this.userId;
    let req: HttpRequest<any> = new HttpRequest("Get", url, {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            "Accept": "text/html",
            "Content-Type": "text/html"
        }),
        responseType: "json"
    });    
    this.http.request(req).toPromise().then(r => {
      debugger;
      console.log(r);
       return r;
      });
}
```

Backend Code :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/fetchData/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String fetchData(@PathVariable("userId") String userId) {
    System.out.println("calling00");
    if (!MyUtility.checkNullOrZero(Long.valueOf(userId))) {
        try {
            return service.fetchData(Long.valueOf(userId));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Error ", e);
            return null;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason for not using HttpClientModule ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) { }

getRequest(){
   return this.http.get(reqUrl).toPromise()
}
```